# php displaying as plain text

Tags: php, apache, flash-media-server

I have Flash Media Server installed on my Centos OS. Everything is working well except I cannot use php files. When I call a php file inside of my webroot it just displays the php code as plain text. If I search in my httpd.conf file the only reference to php is the following:

> DirectoryIndex index.html index.html.var index.php index.php3
>   index.php4 index.\ php5 index.py index.pl index.rb

Do I need to install php for it to work? How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Go to a command line and type `php -v`.  If it shows up then you already have php.  If not, then in CentOS you should be able to use yum.  Try `yum install php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use command `php -v` and if does'nt show you php version then you have to install PHP. Do

```
yum install php
yum install php-pear
```

then

```
sudo service httpd restart
```

Comment: When I run `php -v` it does respond. I'm guessing here...FMS apache is probably isn't configured with php. I think there is apache for FMS and then one on my computer that came installed with it. Anyway to tell FMS apache to use the already installed php?

Comment: what version you have of PHP then ? Restart apache then.

Comment: I suggest you uninstall flash media server and  reinstall it without apache then download and install apache plus php5 seperate from FMS  you will then have greater support for apache. both apache and FMS will run togeather without any further configuration

Comment: Also of note, I don't have service. I see references of the program around the web but I can't locate it on my machine. It doesn't really matter anyway because I can't restart apache that way...I have to restart it with /opt/adobe/fms/server restart which restarts both fms and apache.

Comment: PHP 5.1.6 (cli) (built: Feb  2 2012 18:24:47) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2006 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2006 Zend Technologies

Comment: I think I will go down the root of uninstalling and installing the new version of FMS anyway. This time I will see about not installing apache. I want to start over and install apache,php,postgresql. Is there a convenient way to install all three together so I don't have to figure out how to enable php or postgresql after the fact?

Comment: `yum install httpd* php* -y` Note that: * indicates install all components and then `yum install postgresql postgresql-server` After this you have to start server `chkconfig postgresql on`
 `sudo service postgresql start`